# Cannot get date from google sheet filled by google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Purpose: To extract date and time from a sheet (created by filled google forms) and use them in the body of email to be set automatically using the script.
Script editor code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 16;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

  for( var j=startRow; j<startRow + numRows; j++)
  {
    var color = sheet.getRange(j, 10).getBackground();
    if("#00ff00"==color)
    {
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
      var row = sheet.getSheetValues(j, 1, 1, 14); //extract j th row till 14/Nth col
      var nameStudent = row[0][0] +" "+row[0][1];
      var time = row[0][6]+" on ";// +row[0][7]+" at "+row[0][8];
      var nameRecipient="Dear "+row[0][9]+",";
      var emailRecipient=row[0][13];
      var subject= "Date and time  "+row[0][5]+" at "+row[0][6];

      var message=nameRecipient+sheet.getRange("L11").getValue()+nameStudent+sheet.getRange("M11").getValue()+time+nameStudent+sheet.getRange("N11").getValue();

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipient, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(j,10).setBackground("#ff9900");
    }
  }
}
```

In output (i.e. email):

The date is entered by person filling google form.
I'm accessing the google sheet created using the forms. Screenshot of the sheet:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hiq6P5ceD-aUZQTDBVUXJYbEk/edit?usp=sharing
The cell (when double clicked) opens a calender shown in the above linked screenshot.
I use the following code (Using Google Apps Script) to get a row from the sheet:

```
var row = sheet.getSheetValues(j, 1, 1, 14); //extract j th row till 14/Nth col
```

In the debugger the date looks like:

```
[["Gaaav", "Budapest","de@erta.com", 9823527827, "San Francisco International Airport(SFO)", 41855, 0.5277777777810115,"Si016", "Al02", "Yaar", "pr", "3112", 94984802569, "jklfasj@kljsafkl.com"]]
```

In the above statement the number 41855 is the date. It actually is 8/4/2014 . But I can't read it . Neither can I read the time, which in the above debug o/p, is 0.5277777777810115.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the debug screen:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hiq6P5ceD-aFlDd2g4SlM5MW8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your time submission is row 14 in your spreadsheet.

convert both the date and time values in to Javascript date objects, then update the date object from the form with the hours and minutes from the time object from the form.

```
 function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var startRow = 16;  // First row of data to process
   var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process

   for( var j=startRow; j<startRow + numRows; j++)
   {
     var color = sheet.getRange(j, 10).getBackground();
     if("#00ff00"==color)
     {
       // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
       var row = sheet.getSheetValues(j, 1, 1, 14); //extract j th row till 14/Nth col
       var nameStudent = row[0][0] +" "+row[0][1];
       var time = row[0][6]+" on ";// +row[0][7]+" at "+row[0][8];
       var nameRecipient="Dear "+row[0][9]+",";
       var emailRecipient=row[0][13];

       // build out the date time object
        var dateInput = new Date(row[0][5]);
       var timeInput = new Date(row[0][6]);
       dateInput.setHours(timeInput.getHours())
       dateInput.setMinutes(timeInput.getMinutes());
       // format the date/time object into a string
       var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(dateInput, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

  var subject= "Date and time  "+ dateString

  var message=nameRecipient+sheet.getRange("L11").getValue()+nameStudent+sheet.getRange("M11").getValue()+time+nameStudent+sheet.getRange("N11").getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipient, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(j,10).setBackground("#ff9900");
}
```

}
}

Comment: My purpose is to extract date and time from a sheet (created by filled google forms) and use them in the body of email to be set automatically using the script.

Comment: So I changed the code to create a string in your code sample that would be "08/04/2014 12:04 PM". You can change that formatting with the last parameter in the Utilities.formatDate method.

Comment: You could also improve your call for the message body,  instead of 3 additional server calls (e.g. sheet.getRange("L11"), etc...), combine them to one...  var messageValues = sheet.getRange("L11:N11");   Then just use messageValues[0][0], etc...;

Comment: I tried your code, it didn't work. It is now showing a date of the year 1969

Comment: Verify that the array indexes are correct.  If this is your form submission sheet, I'd be surprised that row[0][0] would be part of the student's name, typically it's the timestamp of the form submission.

Comment: The indices are correct, pretty sure, because they show a date although the date isn't correct. If I point it to a wrong index the it displays "INVALID date".

Comment: Would you be able to share a copy of the file with me, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: (I've deleted all other data except for the date and time), Refer the **SECOND** sheet in the following link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rnk8K1UlTVKV7MtqKoXaW6wKovJUJQBSVEkZT5C4nM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you format column f Format > Number > Date, and column J Format > Number > Time, this will resolve your issue.  I have tested it against what you have shared with me.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus I did that formatting and all previous code started working.

Answer (score 2):

The values you see in your spreadsheet are dates without formating, you can change that easily in the spreadsheet UI itself by choosing the appropriate format: date for column with `41855` and it will become `4-Aug-2014` and time in the column with `0.5277777777810115` that will show `12:40:00` .

These number are the native values of dates in spreadsheet. days are counted from december 30 1899, if you add 41855 days to this reference you'll get the 4 of august 2014 ! as simple as that ;-)

Time is a decimal representation of the hour-minute-sec (percentage of a 24 hours day which is here 12.666666667 hours in decimal, which corresponds indeed to 12:40:00 :-) so that it can be added to the integer part and give a complete date information.

Once you'll have the format set correctly in the SS the script will read it as date objects., I'd suggest you combine both in a single cell to make the script simpler : create a new column with `=C2+D2` if C and D are the columns for example.

see illustration below :

[image]

---

### EDIT

Following your comment, I ran a test on a copy of your SS using this code :

```
function getDatesAndTime() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1];
  var dates = sh.getRange('F2:F').getValues();
  var hours = sh.getRange('G2:G').getValues();
  var complete = sh.getRange('H2:H').getValues();
  Logger.log(dates[0][0]);
  Logger.log(hours[0][0]);
  Logger.log(complete[0][0]);
}
```

I set the display format of the SS to `date` for column F, `Time` for column G and `date+time` for column H in which I used a formula `=F2+G2`

This can be done with script as well like this (insert right before the `getValues()`):

```
  sh.getRange('F2:F').setNumberFormat('MM dd yyyy');
  sh.getRange('G2:G').setNumberFormat('HH:mm');
  sh.getRange('H2:H').setNumberFormat('MM dd yyyy HH:mm');
```

the sheet with modification is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMki1pvnGWEJDkSacMSKKuvdo0TO4PLOnaPZKrA20FA/edit?usp=sharing) (view only, make a copy to edit) and below is the logger result

[image]

### Note :

be sure to check that Time zone settings are the same in spreadsheet AND in script (pacific time in your test sheet and in mine !)
The hour difference you see in the logger comes from a problem with daylight savings... it is fully explained [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995581/date-time-in-google-sheet-not-transferring-the-correct-time-into-google-calendar/24998740#24998740)

Comment: I'm accessing the google sheet created using the forms. Screenshot of the sheet:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hiq6P5ceD-aUZQTDBVUXJYbEk/edit?usp=sharing
The cell (when double clicked) opens a calender shown in the above linked screenshot.

Comment: which means that is is actually a date value ! And I see also that dates are in the right format. what is the issue then ?

Comment: Refer the link of screenshot of debug screen, in that date and time are number format and not string. When I obtain the date and time from the sheets using the sheet.getSheetValues(j, 1, 1, 14); I get in the numeric format and not the string format. This can be seen here too <br/> [["Gaaav", "Budapest","de@erta.com", 9823527827, "San Francisco International Airport(SFO)", 41855, 0.5277777777810115,"Si016", "Al02", "Yaar", "pr", "3112", 94984802569, "jklfasj@kljsafkl.com"]] My end objective is just to insert this date and time in the body of an email.

Comment: I'm sharing the sheet. See if you an extract the date and time values in the form of a string. Refer the **SECOND** sheet in the following link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rnk8K1UlTVKV7MtqKoXaW6wKovJUJQBSVEkZT5C4nM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the spreadsheet, set the format of column H to date and column G to time (instead of "automatic" in menu"123") and it works as explained in my answer.

Comment: see edit please, I updated a copy of your sheet to make it clear. the SS format setting can be made by script as well

Comment: To get a string from these date objects simply use Utilities.formatDate, wich is Google Apps Script utility to convert date object to string the way you like documentation is pretty clear.