# google spreadsheet time format in 12h, unable to convert in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a set of date time data that is drawn from a database. the problem with it is that the data is separated into two columns, one for date and one for time.

I am trying to write a google apps script that can combine the two of them so I can do some meaningful analysis but to no avail.

I tried the common getDate(), getYear(), getMonth() or concatetating them but it doesn't work.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VjhT7Hu8rl1wZgFxItf3unU8jN9Gw3905dNgQ9qICyI/edit#gid=0

If any one knows how to make this data more manageable please do let me know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parse` in JavaScript to get the number of milliseconds for the date, then add the milliseconds in time to it:

First create a new column to convert the time to a different value:

=TIMEVALUE(C2)

```
4:00:00 PM  0.6666666667
11:44:00 PM 0.9888888889
4:51:00 AM  0.2020833333
8:42:04 AM  0.3625462963
7:15:00 AM  0.3020833333
11:46:33 AM 0.4906597222
12:23:00 PM 0.5159722222
5:28:00 PM  0.7277777778
5:37:00 PM  0.7340277778
12:52:00 AM 0.03611111111
6:00:00 AM  0.25
11:49:00 AM 0.4923611111
```

Then run a script to convert the date to milliseconds

```
var milliSkonds = Date.parse("3/21/2012");
Logger.log('milliSkonds :' + milliSkonds);
//This returns 1332302400000
```

Get the decimal values of the column with the time values. then add the milliseconds and time values together.

```
1332302400000.6666666667
```

That represents 4PM on 3/21/2012

I'm not showing how to retrieve the data out of the spreadsheet with Apps Script, or looping through each row.  This is just a strategy I'm suggesting.

Comment: It may not officially represent that date/time, but I'm simply suggesting a solution.  The part before the decimal does represent that date in milliseconds from a certain time.

Comment: "The part before the decimal does represent that date in milliseconds" indeed but the decimal part is definitely not ! So that in the end the result is simply not true...

Comment: It can still be used for comparison purposes with no problem.  And it could be easily separated back out if there was a need.  It's a completely usable solution.  Whether it's the best solution, or the preferred solution is up to the original poster to decide.

Comment: simply try `Logger.log(new Date(1332302400000.6666666667));
Logger.log(new Date(1332302400000));` and you'll see what I mean, both value are the same, there are no decimal in JS date native values.

Comment: I'm not saying that there is a decimal in JS Date values.  I'm not saying that what is produced is a JS Date value.  It isn't.  It's a value that is unique down to the second.  It can be sorted.  It can be compared.  It can be converted back to it's original date and time.  It can't be converted back in one step.  And if anyone doesn't want the code to be that way, then use an alternative.  There are different ways of doing things.  My suggestion might be inferior.  I'm simply trying to find a solution for someone.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is not correct.  It mixes 2 different things.

In Javascript date and time are the same objects, there is no time object that has no date and no date without time : their native values are milliseconds counted from January 1 1970 at midnight (which is an integer).

In spreadsheets, dates have a native value of an integer representing the number of days since december 31 1899 and time is a decimal value which is the fraction of a day ( 6 hours = 1/4 of a day for example , 0.25 day).

So when you add DATE+TIME (integer+decimal) **in a spreadsheet** you get a full date with time .

But this is not the case in JavaScript of course and you cannot (obviously) add milliseconds and decimal values to get a valid result as there are no decimal values in JS dates.

For full details about dates I'd suggest to search the web and have a look at the [MDN date page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Concerning your specific issue, you can run a small function like below to force the format in your spreadsheet (although you could make it also manually using the 123 menu)

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('A2:A').setNumberFormat('MMM/dd/yyyy');
  sh.getRange('B2:B').setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss');
}
```

and use a third column in your SS to simply add column A and B, you will then get a complete date value (with time, the display format should be automatically right)

If you can't use that simple solution then the combination of date and time will be a bit more complex, have a look at [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995581/date-time-in-google-sheet-not-transferring-the-correct-time-into-google-calendar/24998740#24998740) for some suggestions.

Below is a code that converts all your date and time to JS date objects.

```
function getFullDates(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift();
  for(var n in data){
    var time = new Date(data[n][1]);
    var date = new Date(data[n][0]);
    var hrs = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'HH'));
    var min = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'mm'));
    var sec = Number(Utilities.formatDate(time,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'ss'));
    Logger.log('date = '+Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'));
    Logger.log('time = '+hrs+':'+min+':'+sec);
    var dateAndTime = new Date(date).setHours(hrs,min,sec,0);
    Logger.log('full date object = '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateAndTime), Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'))
  }
}
```

NOTE : be sure to check your SS TimeZone and script TimeZone as well, it seems that you are in GMT+8 China, I tested with these values.

Note 2 : I had to use a small trick in the code above to get hours/minutes and seconds because the normal getHours(), getMinutes() getSeconds() return wrong results. This is a problem that has already been discussed here but I can't remember exactly when and I didn't find the post reference right now...

I show the code for info only, feel free to test to see the issue ;-).

```
function getFullDatesBug(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift();
  for(var n in data){
    var time = new Date(data[n][1]);
    var date = new Date(data[n][0]);
    var hrs = time.getHours();
    var min = time.getMinutes();
    var sec = time.getSeconds();
    Logger.log('date = '+Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'));
    Logger.log('time = '+hrs+':'+min+':'+sec);
    var dateAndTime = new Date(date).setHours(hrs,min,sec,0);
    Logger.log('full date object = '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateAndTime), Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,'dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss'))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question, but maybe my workaround might be usefull for somebody nevertheless.
I had similar; trying to compose a startTime and an endTime on one single date in order to populate options in a form.

Getting data from an active selection in a spreadsheet:

```
var firstRowNumber = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var numRows = sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows();    
var sourceData= sheet.getRange(firstRowNumber, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Then, iterating through the (two) time-values in this dataset and replace the value like:

> Sat Dec 30 1899 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

into the desired representation of time like:

> 0:00

```
for(var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++){
 for(var j = 8; j < 10; j++){
     sourceData[i][j] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sourceData[i][j]), "GMT-8", "HH:mm");
     }
}
```

In order to find out the exact deviation of GMT, I used some trial-and-error values to GMT+. This might cause a problem in different timezones, or with changes of daylight saving time.

On three active rows, this results in usable start- and ending date/time-values:

> Fri Dec 30 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **00:00** Fri Dec 30 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **01:00**
>
> Sat Dec 31 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **01:30** Sat Dec 31 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **02:15**
>
> Thu Dec 29 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **01:30** Thu Dec 29 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) **02:15**

with which I can populate the options in my form.